# How to fix Inno Setup error EndUpdateResource failed (110)

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

When compiling an Inno Setup installer script I get this error

> Line: xx Resource update error:
>   EndUpdateResource failed (110)

line xx contains

> SetupIconFile= pathToIconFile

What causes the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the solution after quite a google session

> Win32 error 110 = "The system cannot
>   open the device or file specified."
>
> It's probably having trouble writing
>   to the newly generated installer.exe.
>   Check the permissions on the output
>   directory, and disable any anti-virus
>   software.

I disabled my anti-virus and the error disappeared.

Comment: I just had to remove the 'Read-only' attribute under the folder properties.

Comment: I had to do the same. Works great!

Comment: I work around this issue by adding ISCC.exe to trusted programs in the anti virus.

Comment: Experienced this issue for the 1st time today with a script that I have been using for years - I needed to reboot then disable AV to get it working, but it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I just wanted to add that if your Inno-setup target directory exists in a Dropbox (or any other cloud storage service) folder, then this error occurs frequently. The solution is to simply pause synchronization while compiling your setup.

Comment: I was looking for issues with the icon file, while the problem was actually with the output file. Trying to delete the output file revealed the problem: it was in use via a network share. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem on Windows 10 with Windows Defender active. I tried first to remove the output folder's "Read-Only" attribute as mentioned above but did not work. Since I did not want to disable the antivirus I had to add the **Output** folder of the Inno Setup Studio to the Exclusion section of Windows Defender:

"*Start*  -> *Settings*  -> *Updates & Security*  -> *Windows Security* -> *Virus & threat protection* -> *Virus & threat protection settings* -> *Add or remove exclusions* -> *Add an Exclusion* of type "*Folder*"

Answer (score 2):

In McAfee I was able to disable the real time protection and it prevented "Win32 error 5:EndUpdateResource failed (110)"

Answer (score 1):

I was using AnyDesk to share my .exe installed directly from 'bin' folder, and once, AnyDesk have occupied this setup file with the same name that INNO Setup would produce, therefore I could not compile anything (110 exception have been shown). Closing AnyDesk solved the problem.

I suppose that active anti-virus defence doing same thing for a brief moment, so as a result - **make sure that nothing is occupying output file name** *(including active anti-virus defence)* and that should fix most of the problems.