# Error when saving to mapped drive in Inno Setup Only

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup, windows-10-desktop, inno-setup-v6

I am experiencing exactly the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951483/error-when-saving-to-a-mapped-drive-in-sublime-only-cannot-save-a-file-with-a-u) the only difference being I am using Inno Setup instead of Sublime Text.

I can read/write to the mapped (Z:) drive with any application (notepad, wordpad, paint, etc...), even dropping into command line I have full read/write access, but Inno Setup does not even save its `.iss` file without giving a "Access is denied" error. As in the linked question, this message also appears to come from Inno itself.

To be clear, I am talking about the Inno compiler editor itself not being able to even save the `.iss` file, I am not talking about what the generated installer is supposed to do.

Unfortunately the accepted solution does not apply to Inno Setup.

I have no clue on what prevents Inno from writing to the mapped drive. As for now the only workaround I have found is to copy/paste the whole Z tree in C, use Inno (without any problem) and then re-copy/paste the whole tree back into Z, which is.. well, rather inefficient.

I am using Windows 10 2004 x64 English International, the shared resource is a NFS export from a linux server. Inno Setup is the latest 6.1.2

UPDATE: I can confirm that Inno Setup is the only application on the PC that can't write to the shared folder. Literally everything else works without any problem.

I tried uninstall/reinstall with no luck. I also tried reverting back up to version 5.5.0, still no luck. I tried to find any log whatsoever, no luck there either. For unknown reasons Inno is denied write to the network drive.

Comment: I have a problem with the inno setup compiler editor itself, it cant even just save the plain iss file. I am not talking about what the created installer will do.

Comment: I can open, edit and save the iss using the notepad with no problem, but Inno keep saying "Access denied" as I hit save. May very well be some windows specific issue i have no idea. Of course compilation on Z fails because of a denied write access.

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable your antivirus. I had the exact same problem and [found this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437844/how-to-fix-inno-setup-error-endupdateresource-failed-110), which worked for me.
In my case, with Avast, I just had to add an antivirus exception for the Inno Setup installation folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6).
If it can help anyone having the same issue.